# Anyway to have more than one extra added to intent?

Tags: android

I want to have more than one extra added to `Intent`. One to hold a `double` and one to hold `long`. Is this possible?

If so, how would I do it and how would I get the information from each extra?

Answer (score 10):

You can add as many extras to an `Intent` as your heart desires, they are all just key value data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("name", "MyName");
intent.putExtra("age", 35);
intent.putExtra("weight", 155.6);
```

And they can be retrieved using the same key names:

```
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
int age = intent.getIntExtra("age", 0);
double weight = intent.getDoubleExtra("weight", 0.0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason i always thought you were allowed only one. This makes things a lot more simpler for me thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra(@ExtraDoubleKey, @ExtraDoubleValue);
intent.putExtra(@ExtraLongKey, @ExtraLongValue);
```

Where @ExtraDoubleKey is a string that you will use to access the extra (i.e. "price" or something), and @ExtraDoubleValue is the value of the extra (the double variable you wish to pass). Similarly for @ExtraLongKey and @ExtraLongValue.

Then to access the extras in your next activity you can use:

```
double doubleValue = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble(@ExtraDoubleKey);
long longValue = getIntent().getExtras().getLong(@ExtraLongKey);
```

to get the value of the double extra with the key @ExtraDoubleKey.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11461530/776075

Devunwired is correct.
But the way i see is
you can keep only one value per Type.
Like one string, one int, one double etc..

You are not capable of containing 2 string values. or two integers.
I have experienced this on a program and i have overcome it by using 
one string and one Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bundle` and pass it as a parameter to the Intent.

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Bundle passData = new Bundle(); //to hold your data
passDataBndl.putString("fname", fname); //put in some String. the first parameter to it is the id, and the second parameter is the value
nextActivity.putExtras(passDataBndl); //Add bundle to the Intent
startActivityForResult(nextActivity, 0); //Start Intent
```